# Processing a file without an extension on my VPS as a PHP script

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

Good day. I uploaded a file to my Ubuntu OS VPS (/var/www). The file's named 'theyu', without extensions. It's a php script, but for some reasons, I don't want to add the extension. 
I'd like to configure Apache to process a request such as say 10.382.234.32/theyu, where 10.382.234.32 is the vps' ip address, as 10.382.234.32/theyu.php

Is this possible? I'd really appreciate answers. I've tried editing the .htaccess file in /var/www using mod_rewrite, and the module is enabled in apache's configuration file. Allow OverWrite is also set to All at /etc/apache2/sites-available/default.

The command I used for rewriting in the .htaccess file was
`RewriteRule ^(theyu)$ /$1.php [L]`

But all I get when I try acessing the it is a page not found error, cos it's processing theyu as a directory.

Comment: Why not just give it some weird extension and have the server handle it as php? Even if you hide the extension with mod_rewrite, you might still be able to see the location (and therefore extension) in the headers if you wanted to inspect them. That would still defeat what you're trying to do right?

Comment: The file has to be saved as theyu.php. It's a processing script to be used with a software, so the software needs to access 'theyu.php' specifically. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have MultiViews enabled on your folder? then you can put it as theyu.php and request it as http://example.com/theyu

Comment: How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: I added this to /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

 <Directory /var/www>
   #Other directives here...
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes MultiViews
</Directory> 

But it still gives 404 directory not found error. Thanks.

Comment: mod negotiation , is needed for it to work. but it should be compiled in by default (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html ), try **+MultiViews** intead of **MultiViews** . I am not all that familiar with apache, as i mostly use lighttpd.

Answer (score 0):

So, I was able to achieve this by turning on MultiViews. Adding `Options +MultiViews` to my htaccess file. 
Though it worked, I still wasn't able to achieve the functionality I wanted with the software.